# Solve for y in $2^{y + 3} = 5^{y}$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Solve for y in $2^{y + 3} = 5^{y}$.

I know that

\begin{align}
\begin{split}
2^{y + 3} = 5^{y} \\
(y + 3) log 2 = y log 5 \\
\frac{y+3}{y} =\frac{log 5}{log2}
\end{split}
\end{align}

and then I got stuck.

Comment: Write $\frac{y+3}{y}=1+\frac{3}{y}$

Comment: @Jennifer Ok I got it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From where you left;

$$\frac{y+3}{y}=\log_2{5}$$ (Change of base formula was used)
$$1+\frac{3}{y}=\log_2{5}$$
$$\frac{3}{y}=\log_2{5}-1$$
Therefore;

$$y=\frac{3}{\log_2{5}-1}$$

---

Alternatively,
$$y=\frac{3\log2}{\log5-\log2}=\frac{\log8}{\log2.5}=\log_{2.5}{8}$$

Answer (score 3):

$$\left(\frac{2}{5}\right)^y=\frac{1}{8}\implies\,y=-3\log_{0.4}2$$